# Passing Data to a Python Web Crawler from PHP Script

Tags: php, python, stdout, stdin, web-crawler

I've got a python crawler crawling a few webpages every few minutes. I'm now trying to implement a user interface to be accessed over the web and to display the data obtained by the crawler. I'm going to use php/html for the interface. Anyway, the user interface needs some sort of button which triggers the crawler to crawl a specific website straight away (and not wait for the next crawl iteration).

Now, is there a way of sending data from the php script to the running python script? I was thinking about standard input/output, but could not find a way this can be done (writing from one process to another process stdin). Then I was thinking about using a shared file which php writes into and python reads from. But then I would need some way to let the python script know, that new data has been written to the file and a way to let the php script know when the crawler has finished its task. Another way would be sockets - but then I think, this would be a bit over the top and not as simple as possible.

Do you have any suggestions to keep everything as simple as possible but still allowing me to send data from a php script to a running python process?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Edit: I should note, that the crawler saves the obtained data into a sql database, which php can access. So passing data from the python crawler to the php script is no problem. It's the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Best possible way to remove dependencies of working with different languages is to use a message queuing library (like rabbitMQ or ActiveMQ)

By using this you can send direct messages from php to python or vice versa...

If you want an easy way out you need to modify your python script(more on the lines of what fabrik said) to poll a database(or a file) for any new jobs...and process it if it finds one...

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't know too much about how python works just treat this like a wild idea.

- Create an XML on your server which is accessible by both of python and PHP
- On the PHP side you can insert new nodes to this XML about new urls with a `processed=false` flag
- Python come and see for unprocessed tasks then fetch data and put sources onto your db
- After successful fetching, toggle the `processed` flag
- When next time PHP touch this XML, delete nodes with `processed=true` attributes

Hope it helps you in some way.

Comment: While this would be a working-workaround, it does not resolve two problems: 1) The crawler would need to check every few seconds if the while was changed. 2) The php script would have to read every few seconds and check if the flag was set to true.

Comment: @Philipp you can run your Python script at every minute/second if you like with cron.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've ended up using a socket. The crawler now has a dedicated thread listening on a specific port. I now can send commands using the webinterface using php sockets. Although it isn't my favorite solution, it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I have good experience of using standard XML-RPC Python library to provide simple RPC interface.
All you need to do is to start another thread in Python script that will process XML-RPC requests from PHP code. PHP have quite mature XML-RPC support with http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/.